# Firebase 9 array from onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

So I need to convert data from Firebase 9 snapshot to an array.

I've came up with something like this, but it doesn't return anything.

**Check comments in my code.**

I suppose, I should use promises, but can't figure out the right way.

```
const fetchNewMessages = async (threadId: string, latestTimestamp: any) => {
  const q = query(threadRef(threadId), orderBy('timestamp', 'asc'), startAfter(latestTimestamp));
  const messages: IMessage[] = [];
  onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    const docs = querySnapshot.docChanges();
    docs.forEach((change) => {
      if (change.type === "added")
        messages.push(fetchDoc(change.doc));
    });
    console.log(messages.length); // here I get 34
  });
  console.log(messages.length); // here I get 0
  return messages.reverse();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to wait for "onSnapshot"

```
  const fetchNewMessages = (threadId: string, latestTimestamp: any) => {
  const q = query(threadRef(threadId), orderBy('timestamp', 'asc'), startAfter(latestTimestamp));
  const messages: IMessage[] = [];
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const docs = querySnapshot.docChanges();
      docs.forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === "added")
          messages.push(fetchDoc(change.doc));
      });
      resolve(messages.reverse());
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: It works now, thank you so much!